# Dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 with an Intel RST SSD

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I'm currently trying to dual-boot Windows 10 with Ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo IdeaPad S340. The machine originally came with a PCIe NVME SSD with Intel Rapid Storage Technology (RST). On my first attempt at installing Ubuntu beside Windows, I quickly realized that Ubuntu could not see my SSD. After a lot of googling, I believe this is a symptom of Intel RST. The machine had room inside for another 2.5" drive, so I bought and installed a SATA SSD in addition to the other SSD. Ubuntu can see the new drive just fine, and it installed perfectly.

The problem now is that GRUB cannot see the Windows SSD to know that Windows exists on the system, so it is not listed as a boot option. Changing the boot order in UEFI settings, I can boot into Windows, where I can see both drives in Disk Manager. There appear to be EFI partitions on both disks - not sure if this is problematic.

I believe I need to either find a way to make GRUB see Windows, or make the Windows Boot Manager list Ubuntu as an option, but I cannot find a way to do either.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You would have to install AHCI drivers into Windows & change from RAID/Intel RST to AHCI. And make sure Windows fast start up is off. Having an ESP on each drive is ok. Or you can just boot from UEFI boot menu.